# Dispose being called multiple times by Microsoft DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm registering a class twice but with different contracts.

```
services
    .AddSingleton<MyClass>()
    .AddSingleton<IHostedService>(sp => sp.GetService<MyClass>());
```

The class also implements `IDisposable` which means the Dispose method will be called on application shutdown. But since it's registered twice, it will be called twice.

Autofac has two ways of solving this:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().AsSelf().As<IHostedService>();
//or
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().AsSelf();
builder.Register(ctx => ctx.Resolve<MyClass>()).As<IHostedService>().ExternallyOwned();
```

But can't seem to do any of those with Microsoft DependencyInjection in ASP.NET Core. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Technically it shouldn't be letting you add a singleton of the same type twice; that's the whole reason it's a singleton.  Since it does I believe it's up to you to set this up differently.  Based on this question and never have tried it myself; I personally feel like this is 2 different bugs in the framework.

Comment: Kirk Larkin is correct as well but this isnt always the case with all Disposable types; unfortunately.  If you're designing the Disposable type then I suggest following that rule.

Comment: The second isn't a type registration. You register a factory method and the factory method resolves `MyClass`, so both are **EXACT SAME INSTANCE**

Comment: @Tseng Yes, they're the same instance. That's the whole idea why it registered like this.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Can't see any answer by Duncan.

Comment: Another option would be to just use Autofac.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes, it's a much more mature container. I could also stop being so OCD about it being called multiple times. :)

Comment: I think the best option is David’s answer, if it’s practical. Otherwise I’d go with Autofac if that’s what you know. Microsoft’s DI is intentionally simple and even if they did accept a feature request for it, it’ll take time to be implemented and available.

Comment: The core of the problem, IMO, is a design flaw in ASP.NET Core, since abstractions, such as `IHostedService`, should [*not* implement IDisposable](https://github.com/louthy/echo-process/issues/27). Your problem would not exist if *the interface* didn't implement `IDisposable`. On top of that, `Dispose` must be able to be called multiple times.

Answer (score 6):

> Dispose method will be called on application shutdown. But since it's registered twice, it will be called twice. . . .Is there a way to solve it?

Yes.  The problem is in your IDisposable implementation:

> If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object
>   must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw
>   an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times. Instance
>   methods other than Dispose can throw an ObjectDisposedException when
>   resources are already disposed.

[IDisposable.Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IDisposable_Dispose)

Comment: This states that the behaviour  _should_  not be a problem. But suppose you are dealing with a badly written Dispose() from a 3rd party?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Then wrap it in a properly-behaving service type and register that.

Comment: Yes, it is solvable. But that wrapper could be quite a hassle. And it does not completely exonerate the DI. That probably makes this is a feature request.

Comment: I don't have a problem with my IDisposable implementation. But Dispose shouldn't have to be called twice.

Comment: @Allrameest: You should always be prepared that a dispose method may be called twice. Also remember, a `Dispose` method should never throw any exceptions, only the class members may

Comment: @Allrameest: By definition of the `IDisposable` contract, as David rightfully points out, you have a problem with your implementation when it can't handle multiple calls to `Dispose`. That implementation is breaking the contract and is violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).